# python web.py web service multiple parameters query not working

Tags: python, web.py

I did a web service using web.py

install web.py
cd webpy
 edit python web service.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

urls = ('/title_matching2','title_matching2')
app = web.application(urls,globals())




class title_matching2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "hello world"

    def GET(self):
       getInput = web.input(name="World")

       processing the data, return the hash table, I wanted 




           return gg

       if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Then I  run this  web service , ./some.py,  and then call:

```
links http://localhost:8080/title_matching2?title=diehard
```

And it returns a hash table it is what I want

But if I run run the web service using  multiple parameters, 
The code is as follow:

```
    usr/bin/env python

    urls = ('/title_matching4','title_matching4')
    app = web.application(urls,globals())




    class title_matching4:
        def __init__(self):
            self.hello = "hello world"

        def GET(self):
           getInput = web.input(title="World",prod="type")

       title1=str(getInput.title)
       prod1=str(getInput.prod)
       processing the data, return the hash table I wanted. 

       return qq

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

and then run
    ./rest9.py
And then I opened a link using links 
  http://localhost:8080/title_matching4?title=diehard&prod=feature
no hash table returned, although I want to have a hash table returned 
Something like below appears on the screening: 
    [1] 1190
I am wondering why?
Why I can not open a link and get a hash table?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Just did it! Any comments, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `[1] 1190` you're seeing isn't from you web.py code (which is correct as written). It is from your shell in response to your 'links' command.

The shell is seeing the unescaped ampersand (&) and putting your `links` command to execute in the background `[1]` with process id `1190`.

Surround the URL with quotes, for example:

```
links 'http://localhost:8080/title_matching4?title=diehard&prod=feature'
```