# web.py multiple parameters query not working

Tags: python, web.py

I have created a web.py service.

Here is thet code:

```
urls = ('/', 'index')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input(url=[])
        print (user_data)
```

This is the url that i try to open:

```
http://webpy_server/?url=http://www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=cat&class_id=4520&page=1
```

But the problem is that web.py service only detects searchtype=cat as a parameter but other parameters are not being sent with url. I confirmed it using print (user_data) and got this outout in console:

```
<Storage {'url': [u'http://www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=cat'], 'class_id': u'4520', 'page': u'2'}>
```

class_id and page are detected as other user_data variables. I hope that my explanation is easy to understand. :)

This question is not related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203256/python-web-py-web-service-multiple-parameters-query-not-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the URL properly.  It should be

```
http://webpy_server/?url=http%3A//www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search.aspx%3Fsearchtype%3Dcat%26class_id%3D4520%26page%3D1
```

The multiple question-marks are messing things up.

(Assuming that cat and the others are meant as parameters to the phonebook, not to your own app.)

Comment: Thanks a million, please would you kindly direct me to some proper documentation of web.py or even some other framework that is better than web.py?

Comment: This particular problem nothing at all to do with web.py, it is completely standard.  Any web server in the world would do the same thing.  Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).